# How to show all the array instead of just the first [0]

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arrays

```
Label lblSize=(Label)list.Items[0].FindControl("lblSize");
```

I have a `DataList` and need to change `Visible` to `false` in those that do not have a value. Like it is now it only works in the first product. How do I change it so it works on all the products and not just the first `[0]`?

Comment: what is your criteria for not having a value?

Comment: You should read about the [for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) and [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) statements. Cycles are basic concepts that will eventually become second-nature to you.

Comment: How about using a foreach loop to iterate through all the items?

Comment: The problem is that I only get one result for the first row in the database, I would like to hide the labels on all the rows. Not just the first row. A foreach loop may do it but I have a problem to make it work with the Findcontrol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824333/how-to-show-all-the-array-instead-of-just-the-first-0/4824385#4824385) will probably work if you just replace `var` with `DataListItem`.

Alternately, a `for` loop should work just as well:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; ++i)
{
    Label lblSize = (Label)list.Items[i].FindControl("lblSize");
    // Do whatever you need to.
}
```

---

**Update**: Just because the question was asked (in a comment): why didn't the `foreach` loop work?

Here's how `foreach` works:

1. It looks for the type's `GetEnumerator` method.
2. In the type of object returned, it looks for the `MoveNext` method.
3. Following a successful call to `MoveNext`, it looks for the `Current` property.

Note that [a strict implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable` is *not* required](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/08/28/pop-quiz-how-do-you-make-your-type-enumerable-using-the-foreach-keyword/)—only those exact criteria I just listed.

Now, a convenient way of equipping your type to be eligible for a `foreach` loop *is* by implementing either `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable`; in the case of the `DataList.Items` property which returns a [`DataListItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalistitemcollection.aspx), the designers chose to implement simply `IEnumerable` (I suspect there is a reason for this—basically all UI controls in the framework are non-generic). The `GetEnumerator` method returns an object whose type implements the simple `IEnumerator` interface, whose `Current` property is just `object`.

What all this means is that if you `foreach` over a `DataListItemCollection`, and you declare the local variable using `var`, the compiler has **no idea** what type of object resides in the collection you're iterating. Therefore it makes a conservative choice: `object` (hover your mouse over the local in Visual Studio to confirm this).

The way the `foreach` construct works, you *can* type the local variable more strongly if you choose (so: `foreach (DataListItem item in ...`); the compiler inserts a cast in the background for you.

To illustrate, I could *attempt* this:

```
List<int> integers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable enumerable = integers;
foreach (string s in enumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

The above will compile—the compiler is accepting on good faith that I knew what I was doing when I wrote `foreach (string s ...`—but it will throw an `InvalidCastException` at run-time.

Make sense?

Comment: how would this make a difference since `Items` is a collection of Items `DataListItem`'s which inherits from `Control`?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I will explain. Give me a minute to update the answer.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now - I just had assumed it's `IEnumerable<T>` - I keep forgetting that classes from before generics use `IEnumerable`. Is there an `AsEnumerable()` extension method for `DataList` as well? -  Great explanation and +1

Comment: @BrokenGlass: What I normally do with types like this, if I want to write a LINQ query for example, is just to call the `Cast<DataListItem>` extension method to turn the `IEnumerable` into an `IEnumerable<DataListItem>`; so: `from item in list.Items.Cast<DataListItem>() ...`

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop would do the trick...

```
foreach( var x in list.Items )
{
  Label lblSize = (Label)x.FindControl("lblSize");
  // whatever you do with lblSize...
}
```

Comment: looks good but I get an error message. There is no definition for FindControl, a using directiv is missing